# Integrating Shopware Onlineshop into existing WordPress

Tags: wordpress, shopware

I'm working in a carpentry. We currently run our Website on WordPress.
My employer is planning to implement an online shop on our website.

I found Shopware to be the best Online shop Tool box.

Is it possible to integrate a Shopware Onlineshop into an existing WordPress website?

Comment: Easiest way - if the WordPress website should stay - would be to add some prominent link to the Shopware Onlineshop under a new subdomain. Or, as Roman wrote in the answer, use the shopware CMS and replace the full website with Shopware. A full integration of WordPress + Shopware is probably very complex and not worth the hassle.

Comment: In stead using Shopware + Wordpress combination. You can simply using WooCommerce plugin in wordpress to allow creating a shop for you. The combination will work but it will be more complex later in future and quite hard for maintenance

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Shopware 6 provides an CMS function, so you could replace your Wordpress-website with Shopware 6.

### Documentation

The [Shopware 6 CMS Extension](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/extensions/cms-extensions) is a extension that is part of the Shopware Professional Edition and provides extended functions for the shopping experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You do not need to replace you wordpress website but may exchange some part of it instead.
For instance just by rendering shopware templates inside of your wordpress templates (iframe).
Shopware 6 has an extended API for dealing with your shop interface.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have wordpress and shopware at same time, you can make integration between both using apis, create apis in shopware and consume them through shopware.
if you want to have just one shop, you have to choose shopware or wordpress/woocommerce

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).